# Local maven repository in Eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

How can I copy a resource during Tycho build from Nexus repository so that it resides in Eclipse install directory once it's uncompressed? My end goal is to copy archived Maven repository to Eclipse install directory and use that as local Maven repository.

In our Eclipse application we use Shrinkwrap Resolver to fetch runtime jar dependencies from Nexus repository and add them to ClasspathContainer. This works well, however there will be instances when application will be running in environment that has no Internet connection. For this we need Maven repository to reside where our Eclipse application is installed - parallel to features, plugins directories; this is the best location I can think of where to host this repository.

Comment: Tycho uses p2 and not Maven repositories. Which artifacts would you like to copy from where to where to do what with them?

Comment: @howlger I updated my post with more information.

Comment: This looks promising https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm